# We have set download directory in Chrome in selenium.But downloading control is going to downloads folder by default automatically

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

We have set the download directory for Chrome using the below code. It's printing the download directory also. But control goes back to the normal downloads folder. Given is the code. Using Chrome version 76.

```
HashMap<String, Object> chromePrefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
chromePrefs.put("profile.default_content_settings.popups", 0);
chromePrefs.put("download.default_directory", webDriverConfig.getBrowserDownloadDir());
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", chromePrefs);
capability.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
```

Answer (score 0):

This code block is run my project try this. maybe resolve your problem.

HashMap chromePrefs = new HashMap(); chromePrefs.put("download.default_directory",downloadFilepath); ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions(); /set Ch/ options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", chromePrefs); DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome(); capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options); driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);

Comment: Can you explain what is this code doing differently?

Answer (score 0):

With this

```
chromePrefs.put("download.default_directory", webDriverConfig.getBrowserDownloadDir());
```

you are just setting the default directory to whatever the download directory already is. Try changing `webDriverConfig.getBrowserDownloadDir()` to a manually typed path `C:\path-to-desired-folder`.